# mysql\ sqlite3- ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid in BookController#list

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, ruby, sqlite

I have this problem, I guess with mysql\ sqlite3.

I followed this tutorial [tutorial](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/ruby-on-rails/rails-database-setup.htm) and my database.yml is exactly like on that tutorial.

after creating Migration and building the controller as the tutorial says, I try to run the webpage, and I get this error:

```
ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid in BookController#list

sqlite3::SQLException: no such table: books: SELECT * FROM "books"
```

I dont understand why the error says `sqlite3` if on `database.yml` I have`mysql`

I shoult note that on `schema.rb`, I can see the table named `books` with its columns

this is the creation of the database with mysql:

```
mysql> create database sqlExample_development;
Query OK, 1 row affected (0.01 sec)

mysql> grant all privileges on sqlExample_development.*
to 'root'@'localhost' identified by 'password';
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.00 sec)

mysql> FLUSH PRIVILEGES;
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.00 sec)
```

this is the database.yml:

```
development:
  adapter: mysql
  database: library_development
  username: root
  password: [password]
  host: localhost
test:
  adapter: mysql
  database: library_test
  username: root
  password: [password]
  host: localhost
production:
  adapter: mysql
  database: library_production
  username: root
  password: [password]
  host: localhost
```

I will be happy for help.

Thanks.

Comment: Did you run `rake db:migrate` ?

Comment: yap.. I followd the tutorial..

Comment: Have you included this: gem 'mysql2' in your gem file.

Comment: ummm I tried to look for this file at /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems
but on the usr\local\lib, I don't have ruby (wierd). I have site_ruby and it is empty

Answer (score 0):

In order to use Mysql, you need to:

Add `mysql2` gem to your `Gemfile`:

```
gem 'mysql2', '~> 0.3'
```

And then configure your `database.yml` file accordingly:

```
development:
  adapter: mysql2               # <-- heads up !!!
  database: library_development
  username: root
  password: [password]
  host: localhost
  pool: 5
  socket: /tmp/mysql.sock
...
```

Of course, you need to create your `library_development` database in Mysql, run `bundle install` in your project directory and then run `rake db:migrate` before you start using the app in your local environment.

Comment: Hi,  I tried to look for this file at /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems but on the usr\local\lib, I don't have ruby folder (wierd). I have site_ruby folder and it is empty...

Comment: Both ``Gemfile`` and ``config/database.yml`` should be on your project directory. You need to add that line to the ``Gemfile`` file, and then run ``bundle install``